# Unable to set payload to match with required format by server

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to download a excel file using a python request.
Below is the actual payload pass by web browser when I download required excel file manually.

I'm using below python code to do the same via automation.

```
import requests
import json

s = requests.Session()

response = s.get(url)

if response.status_code!=200:
        return 'loading error!'

collectionId = response.content['collectionId']

payload = {
                "collectionId": collectionId
            }

response = s.post(url, json=payload)
```

Here I'm getting status code 400.

Can someone please help me to set payload to match with below snapshot.

[image: Snapshot of actual payload pass by web browser]

Comment: Are you sure the url for both get and post requests is the same? Moreover, you should add headers while issuing post requests.

Comment: Yes, Here there are two URLs. I have add headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}. But it was also failed.

Comment: That header is useless. Try adding user-agent, referer, accept e.t.c. If it still fails, think about adding cookies.

Comment: After passing a token in header finally it was working. Thank you very much.